# May the effect of "Seize the Initiative" be applied to multiple allies while rolling for initiative?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, initiative

An inquisitor of the Tactics subdomain get "**Seize the initiative**" at level 1 :

> **Seize the Initiative** (Su): Whenever you and your allies roll for
>   initiative, you can grant one ally within 30 feet the ability to roll
>   twice and take either result. This decision is made before results are
>   revealed. You can use this ability a number of times per day equal to
>   3 + your Wisdom modifier.

May this effect be applied **to multiple allies**, and or **to the inquisitor** itself ?

I would say it may not, but I am really not sure about this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### No, Tactics Domain users can only apply the ability once per initiative.

Because the trigger is Initiative and the ability specifies 'one ally', the trigger is only met once so the the 'one ally' can only be selected once per initiative.

Otherwise the "one" before "ally" is unnecessarily specific. They would have had to write it as 'one ally per use' or 'as many allies as you choose; each selected ally is a use' for you to be able  to use it multiple times in a single combat.

### Yes, Tactics Domain users can select themselves.

[You count as your own ally](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9nda) unless the ability states 'other ally' or you could not be the target of the ability.

Comment: That's a pretty serious *Magic: The Gathering* type ruling. Because it's apparently not an action to use, can you liken the supernatural ability seize seize the initiative to another similar yet clearer ability?

Comment: I see no reason the singular trigger of "initiative" could not be used to activate this ability multiple times.

Comment: I can't seem to find anything else that activates during initiative that *could* affect other characters, at the moment. I'll take a swing at it, but until then I'm sticking with the RAW that 'whenever you and your allies roll for initiative' is a single event that allows you to 'grant one ally within 30 feet' these benefits. Otherwise the 'one' before the word ally seems unnecessarily specific. They probably would have specified 'one ally per use' or 'as many allies as you choose; each selected ally is a use'.

Comment: As a complementary answer, a similar post on Reddit (by someone else) was answered the same way : https://www.reddit.com/r/Pathfinder_RPG/comments/1ze793/clarification_on_tactics_subdomain_seize_the/